# How can I write text with subscripts and superscripts and special characters?

Tags: android, html, unicode, encoding

I have tried to use `Html.fromHtml(String text)`, but it seems that `Html.fromHtml()` is deprecated and does not work. How can I solve this issue?

Here you can see an example:

Sorry, this is what it meant:

```
TextView tv;

private void function(String data){

    if (data.equals("a")) {
        newString+="a";

    } else if (data.equals("x^2")) {
        newString += Html.fromHtml("x<sup><small>2</small></sup>")
    }
}
tv.setText(newString);
```

The result is not x<sup>2</sup>, but x2.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are trying `fromHtml()` and explain, **in detail**, what "odes not work" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I have edited the question to make it more understandable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Html.fromHtml()` with the code below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `newString`. Or, change it to be a `CharSequence`, and use `TextUtils.concat()` to append the `Html.fromHtml()` output to it. As it stands, you are formatting the text... then deleting the formatting by converting it into a `String`.